# Windows Authentication - Check Roles

Tags: c#, wcf

If I have this web.config all the time I can see all WCF. But my role is different. Why application does not check my role?

```
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="COMPANY\Administrators2"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="COMPANY\Administrators2"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WindowsSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFWindowsBasicHttpBinding.Service1Behavior" name="WCFWindowsBasicHttpBinding.Service1">
        <endpoint 
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="WindowsSecurity"
                  contract="WCFWindowsBasicHttpBinding.IService1" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFWindowsBasicHttpBinding.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Selected Authentication

[image]

Rules in IIS

[image]

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba try this

Comment: You want to send the credentials in clear text over an insecure connection? [Here you go](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/07/31/890.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed using link another user  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba